# How to make long math equations beautiful and small to fit in one line?

Tags: math-mode, equations, formatting, amsmath

I am writing a latex report and I have to use one equation but that equation is long enough to fit in one line and if i am using `mathbf{}` it looks very odd.

Here is the code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{SCITEPRESS}     % Please add other packages that you may need BEFORE the SCITEPRESS.sty package.


\begin{document}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{H_{2}^{(l+1)}} = \mathbf{ReLU (\alpha_{22}^{(l)} H_{2}^{(l)} W^{(l)}+\alpha_{21}^{(l)} H_{1}^{(l)} W^{(l)}} \\
 \mathbf{+\alpha_{23}^{(l)} H_{3}^{(l)} W^{(l)}+\alpha_{24}^{(l)} H_{4}^{(l)} W^{(l)} )}
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

it looks like this :

[image]

How can I make it fit in one line with a better look?
Or if I have to split then How to make it look better in split mode?

Thanks

Comment: (1) What is going on with all this boldness? What is the reasoning behind it? (2) I'd add alignment that is `= {} &` on the first line and start the second line with `&`

Comment: @daleif I am new in Latex, I don't know how to format this properly.

Comment: You made the choice to make this in bold. Please explain why? No latex introductions I know of encourage users to make everything in bold. You made the choice: please explain it. And no as long as this is two column mode it will never fit on a single line and changing the font size to make it fit is **never an option**

Comment: @daleif I am just using mathbf to make equations look better. I am looking for suggestion to make the equations better without making it bold.

Comment: You do not add bold to an equation to make it look better. I most cases bold have a specific meaning the the contents you are typesetting. Drop the boldness unless you have a specific reason to make a part of the equation bold. How to typeset thise two lines properly I already explained above. If you are a new latex user I would suggest you read a proper introduction, see for example https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/. Additionally why are you loading: epsfig (have not been recommended since the 90s, pslatex same, what even is SCITEPRESS

Comment: (1) Use `multline` rather than `equation` with `aligned` for single equations that occupy multiple lines. (2) Looks like there is a common factor of W^{(l)}. (3) [Not related to the problem] Don't load `epsfig`; it has been deprecated for about 1/4 century.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should consider a few changes to this equation.

1. Your equation already fits in one line, so why put it on two?
2. It might not be a good idea to put everything in bold, so you could at least reduce the amount of bold used. If you want upright math symbols, you can use the `\mathrm` command.
3. When writing `l` in math, it's often confusing to know if the symbol is an "l" or a "1", so it might be a better idea to use the `\ell` command, which outputs a cursive "l" symbol.
4. You can put bigger parentheses, since what is between them is a little big.

To summarize, I would suggest option (5) or (6) in the following.
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{pslatex}

\begin{document}

Original:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{H_{2}^{(l+1)}} = \mathbf{ReLU (\alpha_{22}^{(l)} H_{2}^{(l)} W^{(l)}+\alpha_{21}^{(l)} H_{1}^{(l)} W^{(l)}} \\
 \mathbf{+\alpha_{23}^{(l)} H_{3}^{(l)} W^{(l)}+\alpha_{24}^{(l)} H_{4}^{(l)} W^{(l)} )}
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

On one line:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{H_{2}^{(l+1)}} = \mathbf{ReLU (\alpha_{22}^{(l)} H_{2}^{(l)} W^{(l)}+\alpha_{21}^{(l)} H_{1}^{(l)} W^{(l)}} \mathbf{+\alpha_{23}^{(l)} H_{3}^{(l)} W^{(l)}+\alpha_{24}^{(l)} H_{4}^{(l)} W^{(l)} )}
\end{equation}

On one line, with $\ell$ and bigger parentheses:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{H_{2}^{(\bm{\ell}+1)}} = \mathbf{ReLU \Bigl( \alpha_{22}^{(\bm{\ell})} H_{2}^{(\bm{\ell})} W^{(\bm{\ell})}+\alpha_{21}^{(\bm{\ell})} H_{1}^{(\bm{\ell})} W^{(\bm{\ell})}}
 \mathbf{+\alpha_{23}^{(\bm{\ell})} H_{3}^{(\bm{\ell})} W^{(\bm{\ell})}+\alpha_{24}^{(\bm{\ell})} H_{4}^{(\bm{\ell})} W^{(\bm{\ell})} \Bigr)}
\end{equation}

On two lines, with $\ell$ and bigger parentheses:
\begin{multline}
\mathbf{H_{2}^{(\bm{\ell}+1)}} = \mathbf{ReLU \Bigl( \alpha_{22}^{(\bm{\ell})} H_{2}^{(\bm{\ell})} W^{(\bm{\ell})}+\alpha_{21}^{(\bm{\ell})} H_{1}^{(\bm{\ell})} W^{(\bm{\ell})}} \\
\mathbf{+\alpha_{23}^{(\bm{\ell})} H_{3}^{(\bm{\ell})} W^{(\bm{\ell})}+\alpha_{24}^{(\bm{\ell})} H_{4}^{(\bm{\ell})} W^{(\bm{\ell})} \Bigr)}
\end{multline}

On one line, with $\ell$, bigger parentheses, and less bold:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{H}_2^{(\ell+1)} = \mathbf{ReLu}\Bigl( \alpha_{22}^{(\ell)} \mathbf{H}_2^{(\ell)} \mathbf{W}^{(\ell)} + \alpha_{21}^{(\ell)} \mathbf{H}_1^{(\ell)} \mathbf{W}^{(\ell)} + \alpha_{23}^{(\ell)} \mathbf{H}_3^{(\ell)} \mathbf{W}^{(\ell)} + \alpha_{24}^{(\ell)} \mathbf{H}_4^{(\ell)} \mathbf{W}^{(\ell)} \Bigr)
\end{equation}

On one line, with $\ell$, bigger parentheses, and \texttt{mathrm} instead of \texttt{mathbf}:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{H}_2^{(\ell+1)} = \mathrm{ReLu}\Bigl( \alpha_{22}^{(\ell)} \mathrm{H}_2^{(\ell)} \mathrm{W}^{(\ell)} + \alpha_{21}^{(\ell)} \mathrm{H}_1^{(\ell)} \mathrm{W}^{(\ell)} + \alpha_{23}^{(\ell)} \mathrm{H}_3^{(\ell)} \mathrm{W}^{(\ell)} + \alpha_{24}^{(\ell)} \mathrm{H}_4^{(\ell)} \mathrm{W}^{(\ell)} \Bigr)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```